# overflow-y: scroll not working for iframe

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an `iframe` in which I need a vertical scrollbar, using CSS.

I am using the following CSS:

```
.subject iframe {
    border:medium none;
    height: 40px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The code works for Firefox and IE8, but not for IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: i dont think you need -ms-overflow-y

Comment: yes...i know that....just tried

Comment: can you set up a fiddle

Comment: Try setting overflow-x to scroll or try to set the overflow-y:scroll; explicitly on the iframe, also, you probably need to set overflow:hidden;

Comment: iframe is dynamically coming...and it is set using GWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know your problem but this works fine on IE9. `height` set to 40. and vertical `scroll`
it is the same code. without `-ms-overflow-y`

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/WY8DP/

Comment: True, even working for me on jsFiddle on IE9..
but when i am adding the same and compile GWT
it not working !

Comment: @AshwinHegde ok so your problem is specific to GWT. i dont know anything about it really.